# I need to clean up my campaigns plot holes for the second half of it

Tags: warlock, wild-magic

This is my first time DMing a game and I did not take it seriously at all for the first half. I gave a warlock wild magic because I thought it would be funny, but now that I want to actually do a good job there have been multiple memorable things that have happened because of Wild Magic. I told the players that because of my bad judgement we should retcon the Wild Magic curse completely. They agreed this should happen but between the last session and now they have brought up a lot of valid things like "Ok so Ashe (The warlock) is now 16 because they got wild magic and got aged down. So how did that happened if we say that Wild Magic never happened?" I am in a real jam here and it seems like this may ruin the rest of the campaign. How can I fix this cleanly, or should the group and I just go with "It was a big mistake on my part and I will try to run a better thought out game from here on out"?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Take the [tour] if you haven't already. What RPG system and edition are you playing? What do you mean by "I gave a warlock wild magic"? If you're playing 5e, are you using the official wild magic surge table? When you say, "How can I fix this cleanly", what is the specific goal you are trying to accomplish that you're asking for our help with?

Answer (score 4):

#### I recommend to avoid retcons in general

Retcons are very difficult to apply because, as you've noticed, there are so many knock-on effects. Players can't trust their own memory of events to be accurate. It breaks consistency, and so on. In my experience as a DM, retcons should be reserved for only the most extreme cases, such as a campaign-ending mistake.

In your particular situation, I recommend one of three options:

- Something in your game world cures the warlock's wild magic curse. The past remains exactly as it was, but from now on the warlock does not have this power. This solves the balance and tone issues without a retcon.
- Consider allowing the warlock to keep the ability. Perhaps your players may enjoy such a wacky ability, and the balance issue isn't so huge.
- Or, retain the wild magic, but the DM decides when the wild magic effect works, and it rarely takes effect.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I found a way to remove the curse!

Answer (score 3):

**Why retcon it?**

As you've stated, things have already happened and are now part of your group's story. Why change what happened in the past? Just like you decided to include such a curse from a storytelling perspective, couldn't you find a way to remove it in a similar fashion?

How was this curse acquired? Why would the character want to remain cursed? If the player agrees that the wild magic should go, couldn't his character (and hopefully the rest of the party) go on a quest to remove the curse?

The fact that the affected character is a warlock makes this even easier. If the wild magic comes from his Patron, why couldn't they simply remove it? Maybe it's no longer funny and/or useful to them. Maybe the curse is interfering with the Patron's objectives (the warlock is a bit less reliable now that anything can happen around him). Can't they order the warlock to find a way to remove the curse? Maybe threaten to stop granting him powers if he doesn't make this a priority?

All I see is an opportunity for a cool quest! You said you wanted to take this seriously and make it more fun. Why not start there?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I found a way to cleanly remove it from game play! I appreciate the in site though!